# Insert an image after after text in a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am quite new to apps script and managed to put the following script together as an independent mail merge;

```
function sendEmail() {

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").activate();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();

var templateText = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email 
Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();

var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

if((lr-1) > quotaLeft){
Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " email quota left for the 
day and you are trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. 0 emails were 
sent"); 
} else {

for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
var SiteURL = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
var FirstName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

var messageBody = templateText.replace("{{First Name}}",FirstName);
var subjectline = "Looking to partner with " + SiteURL;


MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectline, messageBody);

} // close for loop

}  // close else statement

}
```

I have been searching the past couple days to try and insert an image from the web after the message body but it seems to be beyond my levels of comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like send an embedded image inside the email, you need to provide htmlBody to the options object. Here's a snippet.

```
var messageBody = templateText.replace("{{First Name}}",FirstName);
var imageUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"

var htmlBody = messageBody + "<br><img src='" + imageUrl + "'>";

MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectline, messageBody, {htmlBody: htmlBody});
```

Comment: Hi Amit, the image comes through now, however, the email body has lost all it formatting ie paragraphs and line spaces. It is now showing as 1 piece of block text. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You should format your email as HTML, not plain text.